# SourceTree cannot clone or fetch or anything

Tags: authentication, github, repository, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I've been using SourceTree for 10 years and now I cannot even access my repos!

## 1-1. Clone from BitBucket using Remote tab

When I tried to Clone my repo in BitBucket, I chose the repo from Remote tab and on the Clone tab, there was an error, "**Repository Type: This is not a valid source path / URL**"

- "Details..." shows!

> error: remote: Invalid credentials
>
> fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://bitbucket.org/xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx.git/'

I'm still able to access the same repo from another PC.
On this PC my GitHub account in SourceTree is stored with Authentication:Basic and Protocol: HTTPS. Authentication:Basic seemes discontinued, but it's apparently still working.

## 1-2. Clone from Bitbucket buttons

1. From my Bitbucket repo, I click **Clone** button and then **Clone in SourceTree** button
2. And then SourceTree shows  "**Repository Type: This is not a valid source path / URL**"

According to this
https://mulcas.com/this-is-not-a-valid-source-path-url-sourcetree/

Tools > Options > Git > Git Version > **Update Embedded**.

This allowed to move one step further.

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/I-always-get-a-popup-credential-helper-selector-asking-me-to/qaq-p/1465880

## 2. Fetching for a Repo that was cloned from GitHub with GitHub desktop

- GitHub desktop showed no problem
- When I tried to Fetch,

> remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
>
> remote: Please see [https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about->](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-%3E) remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
>
> fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/xxxxx/xxxxx/'

I looked at the web page and prepared a personal access token (classic) for GitHub.

1. From Option > Authenticaiton > Accounts > selected an account for GitHub.
2. Selected Authentication: Personal Access Token
3. Refreshed Personal Access Token and pasted the newly generated personal token
4. Login Failed. Authenticatoin failed for GitHub with username xxxxx - please check your account settings

I'm using Windows 11.

I couldn't find a solution in the Internet. Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 2):

I had to do these:

According to this
https://mulcas.com/this-is-not-a-valid-source-path-url-sourcetree/

Tools > Options > Git > Git Version > Update Embedded.

This allowed to move one step further.

Then I also had to do this:

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/I-always-get-a-popup-credential-helper-selector-asking-me-to/qaq-p/1465880